# Wordpress rewrite slug = post_meta

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

At this time I have  2 custom post-type **item, projects**, made custom field for attach **project post** in **item post** (custom field save post_id)

I want use attached project post-name in link:

Current link structure: 

**domain / {item-post-type-slug} / {item-name}**

I want change to:
**domain / {project->post_name} / {item-name}**

With current code should flush rewrite rules on every save/delete action on projects post-type?

How to redirect old link structure to the new ?

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );  
function add_rewrite_rules() {  

    $arg = array(
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'no_conflict' => '1',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );

    $projects= new WP_Query($arg);

    while($projects->have_posts() ) : $projects->the_post();

        global $post;
        add_rewrite_rule(  $post->post_name.'/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?item=$matches[1]', 'top');

    endwhile;
} 

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function custom_permalinks( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'item' )
        return $permalink;

    $project_id = get_field('project', $post->ID);
    $project = get_post($project_id);

    $new_permalink = str_replace("item", $project->post_name, $permalink);

    return $new_permalink;
}
```

For flush rewrite rules using

```
function flush_project_links( $post_id) {

if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'projects' )
        return;

flush_rewrite_rules();

}
add_action('delete_post', 'flush_project_links', 99, 2);
add_action('save_post', 'flush_project_links', 99, 2);
```

but it's work only on second time when update post

**UPDATED:**
flush rewrite fixed:

```
function flush_project_links( $post_id) {

   if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'projects' )
        return;

   add_rewrite_rules()
   flush_rewrite_rules();

}
add_action('delete_post', 'flush_project_links', 99, 2);
add_action('save_post', 'flush_project_links', 99, 2);
```

and removed **add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );**